# Android Voice Recognition (in Search Widget) using given word list

Tags: android, search, voice-recognition

Is it possible to restrict voice search search widget to look for a match near to a given set of words. For example if I am using it to search over a list of names, its not meaningful as names are often corrected to some words.

Answer (score 2):

If you use 3rd party Android recognition from Nuance (The people behind DragonDictate), it supports a "grammar mode" where you can somewhat restrict the phrases that will be recognised during recognition.

Importantly, if you add unusual names into a Custom Vocabulary, they SHOULD become recognizable (Complex pronunciation issues aside)

You can find information if you dig through:
http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com ,
looking for 'Custom Vocabularies'. Grammar mode is essentially a special mode of custom vocabularies.

At the time of writing, there was a document here that makes some mention of grammar mode: 
http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/downloads/custom_vocabulary/Guide_to_Custom_Vocabularies_v1.5.pdf - It only really becomes clear when you try to progress in their provisioning web GUI.

You have to set up an account, and jump through other hoops, but there is a free tier. This is the only potential way I have found to constrain a recognition vocabulary.
Well, short of running up PocketSphinx, but that is still described as a 'Research' 'PreAlpha'.

No, I don't work for Nuance. Not sure anyone does. They may have all been eaten by zombies. You would guess as much reading their support forums. They never reply.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Kaarel, I guess answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at recognition from AT&T.
They have a very feature-rich web API, including full grammar support. I only found out about it recently!

1,000,000 transactions per month for free. Generous!

Look for 'AT&T API Program'. Weird name.

Link at time of writing:
http://developer.att.com/apis/speech

Unfortunately for me, no Australian accent language models at time of writing. Only US and UK English. Boooo.

EDIT: Some months after I submitted the above, AT&T retired the service mentioned. It seems everyone just wants a 'dumbed down' API where you just call a recognizer, and it returns words. Sure, that is of course the holy grail, but a properly designed, constrained grammar will generally work better. As someone with speech skills, the minimalism of the common Speech APIs today is really frustrating...